# For loop and if for multiple conditions and change another column in the same row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to have a change a column if some strings are in the other column in the same row. I am new to Pandas.

I need to change the price of some oranges to 200 but not the price of 'Red Orange'. I cannot change the name of the "fruits". It is a much longer string and I just made it shorter for convenience here.

```
    fruits                         price
    Green apple from us            10
    Orange Apple from US           11
    Mango from Canada              15
    Blue Orange from Mexico        16
    Red Orange from Costa          15
    Pink Orange from Brazil        19
    Yellow Pear from Guatemala     32
    Black Melon from Guatemala     4
    Purple orange from Honduras    5
```

so that the final result would be

```
    fruits                         price
    Green apple from us            10
    Orange Apple from US           11
    Mango from Canada              15
    Blue Orange from Mexico        200
    Red Orange from Costa          15
    Pink Orange from Brazil        200
    Yellow Pear from Guatemala     32
    Black Melon from Guatemala     4
    Purple orange from Honduras    5
```

I tried

```
    df.loc[df['fruits'].str.lower().str.contains('orange'), 'price'] = 200
```

But this produces total of 4 items to change its price instead of only 2 items.

I have used for loop once and that changed the entire column to change its price.

Comment: This is tricky because orange is a fruit and a color. Also not every fruit is described by a color as in the case of mango.

Comment: Yeah which is why I would like to know how to set up multiple conditions set up in Pandas... So different from regular python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.loc[((df['fruits'].str.contains('orange')) & (~df['fruits'].str.contains('Red'))),'price'] = 200
```

We check for oranges and `~` to confirm red is not present in the string. If both conditions are true, price change to 200

Comment: Thank you! It was just what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex:

```
import re

df.loc[df['fruits'].str.lower().str.contains(r'(?<!red) orange', regex = True), 'price'] = 200
```

`(?<!red)` is a negative look behind. So if behind orange is red it wont match it. It also ensure its the second word with the mandatory space before the word orange, so you wont have to worry about it been the color describing something.